# Variable value is stuck to 0 (inside function)

Tags: javascript

Inside *computeDistance* function, the value of x, y and dist will be 0 all the time no matter the values of the parameters.

```
function computeDistance(loA, laA, loB, laB) {
    var dist = 0;
    printErr("++++Parameters inside computeDistance: loA, laA, loB, laB");
    printErr("++++Parameters inside computeDistance:", loA, laA, loB, laB);

    var x = (loB - loA) * Math.cos( (laA + laB) / 2 );
    printErr("++++Inside computeDistance, x=",x);
    var y = (laB - laA);
    printErr("++++Inside computeDistance, y=",y);
    dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2)) * 6371

    return dist;
}
```

Here is an example of call and output:

```
++++Parameters inside computeDistance: loA, laA, loB, laB
++++Parameters inside computeDistance: 0.05235987755982988 0.7504915783575616 0.05235987755982988 0.7504915783575616
++++Inside computeDistance, x= 0
++++Inside computeDistance, y= 0
```

Why are **x** and **y** values stuck 0?

Comment: Simply. Because `loB - loA` is always `0` for your input

Comment: No, `loB - loA` it's `0.05235987755982988 - 0.05235987755982988 ` which is `0`. Please have a look to your input order.

Comment: `laB` and `laA` are also equal, consequently `y = (laB - laA)` is also `0`.

Comment: Swap your input param.You will get something for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because loB - loA is always 0 for your input and  laB and laA are also equal, so

```
x = (loB - loA) **is 0**

y = (laB - laA) **is also 0**
```

**Swap your input param.You will get something for sure**

```js
function computeDistance(loA, laA, loB, laB) {

    var dist = 0;
    console.log("++++Parameters inside computeDistance: loA, laA, loB, laB");
    console.log("++++Parameters inside computeDistance:", loA, laA, loB, laB);

    var x = (loB - loA) * Math.cos( (laA + laB) / 2 );
    console.log("++++Inside computeDistance, x=",x);
    var y = (laB - laA);
    console.log("++++Inside computeDistance, y=",y);
    dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2)) * 6371

    return dist;
}

console.log(computeDistance(0.7504915783575616,0.05235987755982988, 0.05235987755982988,0.7504915783575616));
```

Answer (score 2):

@Elliad Because you're inputting same loB, loA values, and will obviously return 0.
Please check the inputs

```
loA :  0.05235987755982988
loB : 0.05235987755982988
```

loB- loA = 0